# How to take 2 points from One featureClass, create a line between those points, and add the line to a new featureClass (aka Shape File)?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, polyline-creation, feature-class, cursor

I'm a total noob/beginner in ArcObjects. I'm coding in C#. 
I want to extract 2 points from a given featureClass, create a straight line between those 2 points, create a new feature class and add those points to the new featureClass.
The following is code (I have taken a lot of code from internet), but I am facing problems.

```
some_function()
{
        IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = new FileGDBWorkspaceFactory();
        IWorkspace workspace = workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(@"myGDB1.gdb", 0);

        IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = workspace as IFeatureWorkspace;
        IFeatureClass fc_tenActors = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("ten_points");



        ISpatialReference lineFeatureSpatialReference = GetSpatialReference(fc_tenActors);
        IFeatureClass fc_line1 = IFeatureWorkspace__CreateFeatureClass(featureWorkspace, "Line1", lineFeatureSpatialReference);
        fc_line1 = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("Line1");
        IFeatureCursor featureCursorInsert = fc_line1.Insert(true);
        IFeatureBuffer featureBufferInsert = fc_line1.CreateFeatureBuffer();

        IFeature pFeature1 = fc_tenActors.GetFeature(3);
        IGeometry pFirstPointShape = pFeature1.Shape;
        IPoint pFirstPoint = pFirstPointShape as IPoint;

        IFeature pFeature2 = fc_tenActors.GetFeature(4);
        IGeometry pSecondPointShape = pFeature2.Shape;
        IPoint pSecondPoint = pSecondPointShape as IPoint;

  //************* PROBLEM HERE************************************
        IFeature pLine = CreateSegment(pFirstPoint, pSecondPoint);  
 //************* PROBLEM HERE**************************************
  //  This is problem. pLine is empty after this statement.

        featureBufferInsert.Shape = pLine.Shape;  


        AddFields(featureBufferInsert, pLine);
        featureCursorInsert.InsertFeature(featureBufferInsert);
        featureCursorInsert.Flush();

}


public static IFeature CreateSegment(IPoint pFrom, IPoint pTo)
    {
        Line line = new LineClass();
        line.PutCoords(pFrom,pTo);
        return line as IFeature;
    }

private static void AddFields(IFeatureBuffer featureBuffer, IFeature feature)
    {
        // Copy the attributes of the orig feature the new feature
        IRowBuffer rowBuffer = (IRowBuffer)featureBuffer;
        IFields fieldsNew = rowBuffer.Fields;

        IFields fields = feature.Fields;
        for (int i = 0; i <= fields.FieldCount - 1; i++)
        {
            IField field = fields.get_Field(i);
            if ((field.Type != esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeGeometry) &&
                (field.Type != esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeOID))
            {
                int intFieldIndex = fieldsNew.FindField(field.Name);
                if (intFieldIndex != -1)
                {
                    featureBuffer.set_Value(intFieldIndex, feature.get_Value(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The code is in VB, but translating to C# should be trivial.

First, create your featureclass:

```
Public Function CreateStandaloneFeatureClass(ByVal workspace As IWorkspace, ByVal featureClassName As String, ByVal fieldsCollection As IFields, ByVal shapeFieldName As String) As IFeatureClass
    Dim featureWorkspace As IFeatureWorkspace = CType(workspace, IFeatureWorkspace)
    Dim fcDesc As IFeatureClassDescription = New FeatureClassDescriptionClass()
    Dim ocDesc As IObjectClassDescription = CType(fcDesc, IObjectClassDescription)

    ' Use IFieldChecker to create a validated fields collection.
    Dim fieldChecker As IFieldChecker = New FieldCheckerClass()
    Dim enumFieldError As IEnumFieldError = Nothing
    Dim validatedFields As IFields = Nothing
    fieldChecker.ValidateWorkspace = workspace
    fieldChecker.Validate(fieldsCollection, enumFieldError, validatedFields)

    ' The enumFieldError enumerator can be inspected at this point to determine
    ' which fields were modified during validation.
    Dim featureClass As IFeatureClass = featureWorkspace.CreateFeatureClass(featureClassName, validatedFields, ocDesc.InstanceCLSID, ocDesc.ClassExtensionCLSID, esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple, shapeFieldName, "")
    Return featureClass
End Function
```

Now query for the two IPoint features that you want to make a line from. You can either create them here using IPoint.PutCoords() or get them from elsewhere. Create your line and store it in the featureclass.

```
Dim FirstPoint As IPoint = 'get your point. Can store a previous point or use PutCoords() method to create from a lat long.
Dim SecondPoint As IPoint = 

Dim polyline As IPolyline = new Polyline
 polyline.FromPoint = FirstPoint
 polyline.ToPoint = SecondPoint
 Dim feature As IFeature = featureClass.CreateFeature
 feature.Shape = polyline
 feature.Store()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C# developer I use VB but I think the problem is *in* your CreateSegment function.

You appear to be returning an **IFeature** object when you are creating an **ILine** object.

I'm going to guess the code should be:

```
public static ILine CreateSegment(IPoint pFrom, IPoint pTo)
{
    ILine line = new LineClass()
    line.PutCoords(pFrom,pTo)
    return line as ILine;
}
```

and your call to this function should be:

```
ILine pLine = CreateSegment(pFirstPoint, pSecondPoint);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quite some basic code in order to store your line feature into your database. First, it should be a polyline instead of line, which adds supports for multiple segments. Second you should start editing before creating a feature.

I rewrote the code from scratch but in VB.NET, you should be able to convert it easily or use it directly.

Note: you don't have to start the editing from ArcMap to do that, this code starts, stops and save edits.

```
Public Sub CreateLineFeatureBetweenTwoPoints(ByVal pWorkspace As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspace, ByVal pLineFeatureClass As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass, ByVal pFromPoint As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeature, ByVal pToPoint As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeature)

    Dim pLineGeometry As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPolyline
    pLineGeometry = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Polyline

    Dim pPointCol As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPointCollection

    pPointCol = pLineGeometry

    pPointCol.AddPoint(pFromPoint.Shape)
    pPointCol.AddPoint(pToPoint.Shape)
    'retrive the spatial reference
    pLineGeometry.SpatialReference = pFromPoint.Shape.SpatialReference

    Dim pLineFeature As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeature

    'start editing that is an improtant step
    Dim pWorkspaceEdit As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspaceEdit
    pWorkspaceEdit = pWorkspace
    pWorkspaceEdit.StartEditing(False)
    pWorkspaceEdit.StartEditOperation()

    pLineFeature = pLineFeatureClass.CreateFeature
    pLineFeature.Shape = pLineGeometry
    pLineFeature.Store()

    pWorkspaceEdit.StopEditOperation()
    pWorkspaceEdit.StopEditing(True)

End Sub
```

And here is how you call the function.

```
Private Sub MainSub()

    Dim pWorkspace As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspace

    Dim workspaceFactory As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspaceFactory

    workspaceFactory = New ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory

    'open the path to your GDB
    pWorkspace = workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile("c:\test.gdb", 0)

    Dim pFWorkspace As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace

    pFWorkspace = pWorkspace
    Dim pPointClass As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass
    pPointClass = pFWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("PointFC") 'this is your fc class

    Dim pLineClass As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass

    pLineClass = pFWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("LineFC") 'this is your fc class

    Dim pPoint1 As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeature
    Dim pPoint2 As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeature

    pPoint1 = pPointClass.GetFeature(1)
    pPoint2 = pPointClass.GetFeature(2)

    CreateLineFeatureBetweenTwoPoints(pWorkspace, pLineClass, pPoint1, pPoint2)

End Sub
```

[image: The result will look like this]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save feature (people already told how create feature) in .shp, you can use official documentation:

http://www.edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/91E3E8A0-D355-43D2-A201-0A8CEB719334.htm - how convert feature to new shapefile.

But if you do not like write many lines of code, you can:

- At the beginning, create this shapefile (by hands - in ArcMap, in program you only open this file)
- And then (in code) add new feature in this file. For example, if you want to save points in your file. Here `featureClass` is shapefile .shp, `feature` is a new object.

  ```
  ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint point = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Point();
  point.X = lon; point.Y = lat;
  IFeature feature = featureClass.CreateFeature();
  feature.Shape = point;

  feature.Store();
  ```

***Update*** If you want to create feature, you can

- create polyline

  ```
  IPolyline polyline= new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Polyline() as IPolyline;
  polyline.FromPoint = fromPoint;
  polyline.ToPoint = toPoint;
  ```

  - create feature

    ```
    IFeature feature = featureClass.CreateFeature();
    feature.Shape = polyline;
    feature.Store();
    ```

What's the problem?